# CSS is only drawing left and top borders, ignoring right and bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, function

So I have this array

```
[["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1"],
    ["1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","0","1","1"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"]]
```

That represents this map

[image]

And this function that will draw a border to a blank tile, based on where the 1 is positioned in relation to the 0.

```
function lagTile(color,a,b){
var div=document.createElement("div");
var size=32;
div.style.width=div.style.height=size+"px";
div.style.left=a*size+"px";
div.style.top=b*size+"px";
canvas.appendChild(div);
if(color.substr(color.length-3,color.length)=="png"){
    div.style.backgroundImage="url(map/"+color+")";
}else{
    div.style.backgroundColor=color;
}
if(b>0 && map[b-1][a]==1 && map[b][a]==0)
{
    div.style.borderTop="4px solid #630";
    div.innerHTML="Top ";
}
if(b<map.length-1 && map[b+1][a]==1 && map[b][a]==0)
{
    div.style.borderBottom="4px solid #630";
    div.innerHTML+="Bottom ";
}
if(a<map[b].length-1 && map[b][a+1]==1 && map[b][a]==0)
{
    div.style.borderRight="4px solid #630";
    div.innerHTML+="Right ";
}
if(a>0 && map[b][a-1]==1 && map[b][a]==0)
{
    div.style.borderLeft="4px solid #630";
    div.innerHTML+="Left ";
}
```

And gives this result

[image]

As you can see, only the left and top border is displayed. And you can see that the text clearly is correct.

Any suggestions on why the bottom and right borders are not drawn?

Comment: And that's a Wow!!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border is in *addition* to the size, so the elements grow bigger, and is overlapped by those coming after it (below or to the right). So the border is there, just hidden below the boxes drawn after it. See [CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) for how sizing works. In short, the total width of your boxes are `the width of the div + left border size + right border size`.

You can fix this by subtracting the border sizes from the sizes of the divs (for instance, when you add a left-border of 4px, you also remove 4px from the width), or by adding `box-sizing: border-box` to their styling.

Comment: for the sake of your sanity, choose the `box-sizing: border-box` option http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/